# TypeError: Cannot read property 'loggedIn' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am trying to create a nav bar that shows logout when user is already logged in and vice versa. But the buttons have completely stopped showing.

This is bugging me a lot. I don't know where I am going wrong.

I added the app.component.ts file.

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import{Router} from '@angular/router';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private _registerUrl="http://localhost:3000/api/register";
  private _loginUrl="http://localhost:3000/api/login"
_router: Router;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  registerUser(user){
    return this.http.post<any>(this._registerUrl, user)
  }
  loginUser(user){
      return this.http.post<any>(this._loginUrl, user)

  }
  loggedIn(){
    return !!(localStorage.getItem('token'))
  }
  logoutUser(){
   localStorage.removeItem('token')
    this._router.navigate(['/home'])

}
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a  class='nav-link' routerLink='/home' routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
    <a  class='nav-link' *ngIf="!_authService.loggedIn()"routerLink='/register' routerLinkActive="active">Register</a>
    <a  class='nav-link' *ngIf="!_authService.loggedIn()" routerLink='/login' routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>
    <a  class='nav-link' style ="cursor:point" *ngIf="_authService.loggedIn()" (click)="_authService.logoutUser()" >Login</a>



    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>


  <script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "topnav";
    }
  }
  </script>


<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import{AuthService} from './auth.service'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'sams-attendance';
  constructor(private _auth: AuthService){}
}
```

Comment: Consider reviewing the code changes you have made since the buttons stopped working to try to narrow down what could have caused the issue.

Comment: Where are you hooking up the component to the template html?

Comment: I removed the *ngIf property from the buttons and now they are working fine..Just not like I'd want them to work.

Comment: I am doing so that the navbar appears throughout the website usage. Is that a bad practice? @mariocatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're injecting `authService` as private and template can access only public methods, properties.

Try changing your component to:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'sams-attendance';

    constructor(public _auth: AuthService) {}
}
```

While this will work, it might be not the best idea to call service from template directly.

Comment: I especially agree with the last sentence here. Your best bet, when accessing a variable on a service, is to wrap it in the component (or, even better, emit it via an Observable).

Comment: I changed it to public, and it is still showing the same error. :(

Comment: I completely agree to your advice. At this point, my only focus is to actually make it functional. After that, I'll my best to optimize it as much as possible.

Comment: Err, you also reference `_authService` from template, but have `_auth` as a variable in typescript file. That might be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your _authSerivice is undefined check have you passed _authService to templte

Instead you should directly use logedIn in templte

Comment: what does`templte` imply? I am sorry, I am a beginner.

Comment: No problem template means your .html file in your case it's auth.component.html

Comment: mariocatch You are right actually using on mobile so not noticed @aroosha can you please share the app.component.ts file

Comment: Ok now in your .html file instead of _authService use AuthService and have a look if it helps

Comment: @aroosha please have a look at evaldas answer